# Prevent Run or Cancel box from popping up on every use

Tags: windows-xp

I have a small business customer that we just moved to a new building. Other than a new firewall the network is the same.

They access a few programs across the network. Now that they have moved to the new office every time they open these applications they get a run or cancel box, this never happened at the old building and i can imagine that the new FW would cause something like this. Is there a way to prevent this from happening?

I added the unc to trusted sites, but that didn't work ... other than that I do not know what would be causing this.

Comment: can you post a image of the popup box? Are these web or desktop apps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried this?

Run gpedit.msc

Go to User Configuration >> Administrative Templates >> Windows Components >> Attachment 
Manager

Add "*.exe" to the "Inclusion list for moderate risk file types" setting.

Forgot to include the link where I found this info:
http://www.annoyances.org/exec/forum/winvista/1151260847

Answer (score 0):

In Internet Properties- > Security, you need to add the site to the Local Intranet zone.  We have a line added by GPO that looks like this:

`file://*.example.com`