# Group policies to allow chm help files over a network

Tags: security, windows

HI

I need to allow access to a specific set of chm help files.  I'm getting the action cancelled message when trying to view help topics.

I've configured my registry to allow it to work on my local computer but since we have many users one need access to the help files I want to setup group policies on the server as well.

I couldn't find my information on how to do this, I've installed the Group Policy snap-in on our server but I would really appreciate some step-by-step instructions on how to actually setup the policies as I have never done this before.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your easiest bet would be to use [Group Policy Preferences](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=42e30e3f-6f01-4610-9d6e-f6e0fb7a0790&DisplayLang=en) to set the registry values as described in [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/4218/how-to-open-help-chm-files-over-unc-path). This will circumvent the need to write a custom Administrative Template (ADM) file, though there are [some available on the 'net](http://www.winvistatips.com/problem-viewing-chm-files-network-drives-t250591.html) if you'd  rather go the route of the custom ADM.